# Is there a way change an array to a string, split the values at a comma, and join each value via a new line?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing a recursive function that prints an org chart. When logging, this function displays the hierarchy of the chart by adding spaces to the beginning of "subKeys".

**Problem:**
I am having trouble logging the array as a string and splitting the array and joining it with "\n".

**Question:**
Is there a way to implement `.toString().split(",").join("\n")` to `results`?

I've tried `return results.toString().split(",").join("\n")` under // Base case and have been receiving a TypeError, `TypeError: subKeys.map is not a function`.

```
const displayOrgChart = (orgChart) => {

  let results = [];

  // General case
  for (let member in orgChart) {
    if (typeof orgChart[member] === "object") {
      let subKeys = displayOrgChart(orgChart[member]);
      results = results.concat(subKeys.map(subKey => {
        return "  " + subKey;
      }))
    } else {
      results.push(orgChart[member]);
    }
  }

  // Base case
  return results
};

console.log(displayOrgChart(orgChart));
```

Array:

EDITED (5/28 2:52 pm): From object to array.

```
const orgChart = [
  {
    0: {
      name: "Zuckerberg",
      children: {
        0: {
          name: "Schroepfer",
          children: {
            0: {
              name: "Bosworth",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Steve",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Kyle",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Andra",
                },
              },
            },
            1: {
              name: "Zhao",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Richie",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Sofia",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Jen",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        1: {
          name: "Schrage",
          children: {
            0: {
              name: "VanDyck",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Sabrina",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Michelle",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Josh",
                },
              },
            },
            1: {
              name: "Swain",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Blanch",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Tom",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Joe",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        2: {
          name: "Sandberg",
          children: {
            0: {
              name: "Goler",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Eddie",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Julie",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Annie",
                },
              },
            },
            1: {
              name: "Hernandez",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Rowi",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Inga",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Morgan",
                },
              },
            },
            2: {
              name: "Moissinac",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Amy",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Chuck",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Vinni",
                },
              },
            },
            3: {
              name: "Kelley",
              children: {
                0: {
                  name: "Eric",
                },
                1: {
                  name: "Ana",
                },
                2: {
                  name: "Wes",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Current console log:

```
[
  '    Zuckerberg',
  '        Schroepfer',
  '            Bosworth',
  '                Steve',
  '                Kyle',
  '                Andra',
  '            Zhao',
  '                Richie',
  '                Sofia',
  '                Jen',
  '        Schrage',
  '            VanDyck',
  '                Sabrina',
  '                Michelle',
  '                Josh',
  '            Swain',
  '                Blanch',
  '                Tom',
  '                Joe',
  '        Sandberg',
  '            Goler',
  '                Eddie',
  '                Julie',
  '                Annie',
  '            Hernandez',
  '                Rowi',
  '                Inga',
  '                Morgan',
  '            Moissinac',
  '                Amy',
  '                Chuck',
  '                Vinni',
  '            Kelley',
  '                Eric',
  '                Ana',
  '                Wes'
]
```

Comment: `results` is supposed to be an array, you're changing it to a string. So when you return it to the recursive call it tries to use it as an array and it fails.

Comment: you can use `results.join('\n')` to achieve what you want

Comment: Why is the chart using an object like an array? yikes.

Comment: @epascarello - Good question. Edited the object to be an array of objects.

Comment: @VLAZ - Thanks! Super informative. I understand.

Comment: @Yevgen - It's purely an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this:

> Is there a way change an array to a string, split the values at a comma, and join each value via a new line?

Yes, there is. The process is:

1. convert `results` array to string with [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)
2. replace the commas with newlines using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const results = [
  '  Zuckerberg',          '      Schroepfer',
  '          Bosworth',    '              Steve',
  '              Kyle',    '              Andra',
  '          Zhao',        '              Richie',
  '              Sofia',   '              Jen',
  '      Schrage',         '          VanDyck',
  '              Sabrina', '              Michelle',
  '              Josh',    '          Swain',
  '              Blanch',  '              Tom',
  '              Joe',     '      Sandberg',
  '          Goler',       '              Eddie',
  '              Julie',   '              Annie',
  '          Hernandez',   '              Rowi',
  '              Inga',    '              Morgan',
  '          Moissinac',   '              Amy',
  '              Chuck',   '              Vinni',
  '          Kelley',      '              Eric',
  '              Ana',     '              Wes'
];
let tostr = results.toString();
let lines = tostr.replace(/,/g, '\n');
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = lines;
```

```html
Result:
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is a little more complicated than it needs to be. Just using a foreach on the children to call and using a variable to maintain the indent will help.

```js
const orgChart = {
  0: {
    name: "Zuckerberg",
    children: {
      0: {
        name: "Schroepfer",
        children: {
          0: {
            name: "Bosworth",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Steve",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Kyle",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Andra",
              },
            },
          },
          1: {
            name: "Zhao",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Richie",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Sofia",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Jen",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      1: {
        name: "Schrage",
        children: {
          0: {
            name: "VanDyck",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Sabrina",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Michelle",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Josh",
              },
            },
          },
          1: {
            name: "Swain",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Blanch",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Tom",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Joe",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      2: {
        name: "Sandberg",
        children: {
          0: {
            name: "Goler",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Eddie",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Julie",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Annie",
              },
            },
          },
          1: {
            name: "Hernandez",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Rowi",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Inga",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Morgan",
              },
            },
          },
          2: {
            name: "Moissinac",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Amy",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Chuck",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Vinni",
              },
            },
          },
          3: {
            name: "Kelley",
            children: {
              0: {
                name: "Eric",
              },
              1: {
                name: "Ana",
              },
              2: {
                name: "Wes",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

function generateReport (org) {
  const results = []
  function getData(entry, indent) {
    if (entry.name) results.push(indent + entry.name)
    if (entry.children) {
      Object.values(entry.children).forEach(function(child) {
        indent = indent === undefined ? '' : indent + '   '
        getData(child, indent)
      })
    }
  }
  getData({ children: org })
  return results.join("\n")
}

console.log(generateReport(orgChart))
```

Comment: I change the object to an array and ```entry.name``` no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.stringify(results).split(",").join("\n")`.

`JSON.stringify()` will return a string of the array as you showed in the request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

But, as others in the comment said, if in your function you end up returning the string representation, `.map()` breaks because it is not an array.

It's better if you make another function to display the data, and keep the recursive function as is.

As @Omri Attiya said, to get a string from the array you can just use `results.join('\n')`.

```
function getArrayAsString(array){
return array.join('\n');
}
```